# Laravel Carbon get next occurrence of particular date from current date

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

Using Carbon with laravel 5.6.

I want write a code that give me next occurrence of date from current date.

E.g Give next 31st May date

Scenario 1 : 
Input : $currentDate =  '01-30-2019'; // MM-DD-YYYY format  
Expected Output: $next31May = '05-31-2019';

Scenario 2 : 
Input : $currentDate =  '07-04-2019'; // MM-DD-YYYY format  
Expected Output: $next31May = '05-31-2020';

Update:

I tried below code but not satisfy

```
<?php
public function nextOccurance()
{
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $month= $now->month;
    $year = $now->year;
    if($month > 6)
    {
         echo Carbon::createMidnightDate($year+1, 5, 31);
    }
    else
    {
        echo Carbon::createMidnightDate(null, 5, 31);
    }
    exit();
}
?>
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: What did you try? Did you look in the manual?

Comment: $now->addYear(); Use the manual https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub

Comment: To be fair:  It is not as simple as $now->addYear...

Answer (score 5):

```
public function nextOccurance()
{
    // the 31th of May of the current year
    $day = Carbon::createFromFormat('m-d', '05-31');
    $now = Carbon::now();
    // If today after $day
    if($now >= $day) {
       // Gat a next year
       $day->modify('next year');
    }

    echo $day->format('Y-m-d');
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is like to get the next birthday.

```
class Test
{
    public static function getNextBirthday($date)
    {
        // set birthday from current year
        $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $date);
        $date->year(Carbon::now()->year);

        // diff from 31 may to now
        // its negative than add one year, otherwise use the current
        if (Carbon::now()->diffInDays($date, false) >= 0) {
            return $date->format('m-d-Y');
        }

        return $date->addYear()->format('m-d-Y');
    }
}

echo Test::getNextBirtday('05-31-1990');
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish this will help you to fix informed issue.

```
    $event = Carbon::parse('31 May');

    if (Carbon::now() >= $event){
       $nextEvent  = $event->addYear();
    } else {
       $nextEvent  = $event;
    }

    echo $nextEvent->format('m-d-Y');
```

Answer (score -2):

Carbon provides a nice and a fluent interface to this kind of stuff.

You can `lastOfMonth()` to get the last day of month. for adding year you can add `addYear(1)`

```
  $now = Carbon::now();
    $month= $now->month;
    $year = $now->year;
    if($month > 6)
    {
         echo $now->addMonth(5)->lastOfMonth();
    }
    else
    {
        echo $now->addYear(1);
    }
    exit();
}
```